# Python file that runs a bash script which opens a video on VLC not working

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, vlc

I have a working bash script that opens different videos in vlc, based on different keys pressed on terminal. When a video is playing but i press another key, the current video stops, and starts reproducing a new video. But because i don't want the terminal to show, I created a Python script that opens the bash script using the subproccess library. It displays a interface made with pygame (at the moment it just displays a black screen, i need it just for that), it also handles keydown events, which are then sent to the bash script running on the background (which opens vlc and reproduce the video). Whenever I try to open a video this way, vlc just flashes an then dissapears, not reproducing anything at all. The other options (like pressing k to close the program) work just fine, so it must be something with vlc

### the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

kill_vlc () {
    # Check if VLC is running and kill it
    if pgrep -x "vlc" > /dev/null; then
        pkill -x "vlc"
        # Adding a small sleep to ensure VLC fully closes before trying to open a new instance.
        sleep 1
    fi
}

declare -A videos

# load video mappings from file
# the file has this form:
# 3=/path/to/video/video3.mp4
# 2=/path/to/video/video2.mp4
# 1=/path/to/video/video1.mp4

while IFS="=" read -r key path; do
    videos["$key"]="$path"

done < <(grep '=' video_mappings2.txt)


# echo the names
for key in "${!videos[@]}"; do
    video_path="${videos[$key]}"
    video_name="$(basename "$video_path")" # extract filename
    video_name_woutext="${video_name%.*}" # remove extension
    
    echo "> Key: $key, Video: $video_name_woutext"

done

echo ""
echo "> Press a key to play a video (options: ${!videos[@]})"
echo "> Press 'q' to quit the video" 
echo "> Press 'k' to close the program"

# main loop
while true; do
    read -s -n 1 key

    # Close the script
    if [[ $key == "k" ]]; then
        echo "> Closing..."
        
        # Check if VLC is running and kill it
        kill_vlc

        break
    fi

    # Close the video
    if [[ $key == "q" ]]; then
        
        # Check if VLC is running and kill it
        kill_vlc
    fi

    # Check if VLC is running and kill it
    kill_vlc

    # Check if the key is in the videos array
    if [[ ${videos[$key]} ]]; then
        vlc ${videos[$key]} --play-and-exit &
    fi

done
```

### the python file

```
import pygame
import subprocess
import os
import time

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Start the Bash script as a subprocess
bash_process = subprocess.Popen(["./video_player.sh"],
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                text=True)

# Function to display the still image
def display_still_image():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()


running = True
display_still_image()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            key_pressed = chr(event.key)
            print(key_pressed)

            # Send the key to the Bash script
            bash_process.stdin.write(key_pressed + "\n")
            bash_process.stdin.flush()

    # Check if the Bash script has finished
    if bash_process.poll() is not None:
        break

    # Redraw the still image
    display_still_image()

    # Control frame rate
    clock.tick(30)

# Close the subprocess
bash_process.stdin.close()
bash_process.stdout.close()
bash_process.stderr.close()
bash_process.terminate()

# Quit pygame
pygame.quit()
```

I also ran the python script from WSL and from Raspberry OS and the same problem happens.
I tried another video player (mpv) and the problem persists.

Comment: "Python file that runs a bash script which opens a video on VLC" I would advise you to cut out the middle step and reimplement the simple bash stuff in python.  But first I'd figure out why python isn't able to execute VLC by building a minimal python-to-VLC with hard coded path and be sure read from your stdout / stderr pipes to pick up any useful error output.

Comment: Also, please read about [mcve] and read the section [How to turn a bad script into a good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). (this advice applies to all languages, not just bash).  Also https://shellcheck.net is the first place to figure out syntax problems. Be sure to include #!/bin/bash (or other) as your first line of scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: not enough reputation to comment, thus trying to answer

I think your issue is on line 63 of your bash script, which kills vlc on every key press.

```
# Check if VLC is running and kill it
kill_vlc
```

If you really want to go on with this over-complicated structure, I would first make sure the bash script runs properly before integrating in python.

Comment: It's inside an `if` which checks if the key is `"k"`

Comment: @tripleee, you're mentioning line 50, inside the if statement.

on line 63, it is out of any if